# Completely replacing a file (not updating) but keeping the version history

Tags: sharepoint-online, file-upload, version-history

We have a fortnightly planning file on our Sharepoint that had plenty of errors on it so I downloaded a copy and basically redid it. I now want to replace the old file, but I need all of the version history retained as that contains all of our previous fortnight tasking.

Is this possible? If so, how do we do it? I am worried that if I select the replace option when uploading the new file it will wipe all of the version history and treat it as a new file.

Comment: How do you upload the new file? By hand (browser or Win Explorer), PowerShell or Power Automate?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you are uploading a file to SharePoint Document library and select the **Replace** option, it will not erase all version history and treat it as a new file.

**Here is my test:**

1.This is my test file: Demo.xlsx

[image]

2.Download a copy

3.Upload the edited Demo.xlsx and select "**Replace**" option

[image]

[image]

Comment: Ah that's excellent, I should have tried that on another file. Thank you!